# change the response for single request among multiple request in nock

Tags: node.js, express, nock

I have using express and trying to create an API for testing I used nock so i make a get request whose response I don't want to change after that i want to do put request and want to change the response of that part but when i tried to do that i getting error for the first get request that i don't want to change. I am getting the error `Error: Nock: No match for request`

```
  nock(baseURI + '/' + imp.http.relativeURI , { 'encodedQueryParams': true })
            .put('/' +imp.file.fileName)
            .reply(422,
              '<response><errormessage>some error message</errormessage></response>',
              [ 'Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8' ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `allowUnmocked` flag when mocking the second request.
https://github.com/nock/nock#allow-unmocked-requests-on-a-mocked-hostname

```
nock(baseURI + '/' + imp.http.relativeURI , { allowUnmocked: true, 'encodedQueryParams': true })
        .put('/' +imp.file.fileName)
        .reply(422,
          '<response><errormessage>some error message</errormessage></response>',
          [ 'Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8' ])
```

This bit: `nock(baseURI + '/' + imp.http.relativeURI)` is basically telling Nock that you are testing this endpoint, and by default it assumes you only expect the calls explicitly mocked to that endpoint. `allowUnmocked` flips that assumption and allows live calls to proceed as normal unless you explicitly mock them out.